# Type annotation for parsing a string in a JSON file to a range using Pydantic in Python

Tags: python, json, type-hinting, pydantic

I've set up a Pydantic class that's intended to parse JSON files. The *range* attribute is parsed from a string of the form `"11-34"` (or more precisely from the regex shown):

```py
    RANGE_STRING_REGEX = r"^(?P<first>[1-6]+)(-(?P<last>[1-6]+))?$"

    class RandomTableEvent(BaseModel):
        name: str
        range: Annotated[str, Field(regex=RANGE_STRING_REGEX)]
    
        @validator("range", allow_reuse=True)
        def convert_range_string_to_range(cls, r) -> "range":
            match_groups = re.fullmatch(RANGE_STRING_REGEX, r).groupdict()
            first = int(match_groups["first"])
            last = int(match_groups["last"]) if match_groups["last"] else first
            return range(first, last + 1)
```

The generated schema works and the validation passes.

However, the type annotation for the *range* attribute in the class is strictly speaking not correct, as the *range* attribute is converted from a string (type annotation) to a `range` object in the validator function.

What would be the correct way of annotating this and still maintaining the schema generation?
Is there another way of dealing with this implicit type conversion (e.g. strings are automatically converted to int in Pydantic - is there something similar for custom types)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range` is not a supported type by `pydantic` and using it as a type for a field will cause an error when trying to create a JSON schema, but `pydantic` supports [Custom Data Types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#custom-data-types):

> You can also define your own custom data types. There are several ways to achieve it.
>
> #### Classes with **get_validators**
>
> You use a custom class with a classmethod `__get_validators__`. It will be called to get validators to parse and validate the input data.

But this custom data type cannot inherit from `range` because it is final. So you could create a custom data type that uses a `range` internally and exposes the range methods: it will work like a `range` but it will not be a `range` (`isinstance(..., range)` will be `False`).

The same `pydantic` documentation shows how to use a `__modify_schema__` method to customize the JSON schema of a custom data type.

Full example:

```python
import re
from typing import Any, Callable, Dict, Iterator, SupportsIndex, Union

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Range:
    _RANGE_STRING_REGEX = r"^(?P<first>[1-6]+)(-(?P<last>[1-6]+))?$"

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls) -> Iterator[Callable[[Any], Any]]:
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v: Any) -> "Range":
        if not isinstance(v, str):
            raise ValueError("expected string")

        match = re.fullmatch(cls._RANGE_STRING_REGEX, v)
        if not match:
            raise ValueError("invalid string")

        match_groups = match.groupdict()
        first = int(match_groups["first"])
        last = int(match_groups["last"]) if match_groups["last"] else first

        return cls(range(first, last + 1))

    def __init__(self, r: range) -> None:
        self._range = r

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        # Customize the JSON schema as you want
        field_schema["pattern"] = cls._RANGE_STRING_REGEX
        field_schema["type"] = "string"

    # Implement the range methods and use self._range

    @property
    def start(self) -> int:
        return self._range.start

    @property
    def stop(self) -> int:
        return self._range.stop

    @property
    def step(self) -> int:
        return self._range.step

    def count(self, value: int) -> int:
        return self._range.count(value)

    def index(self, value: int) -> int:
        return self._range.index(value)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self._range.__len__()

    def __contains__(self, o: object) -> bool:
        return self._range.__contains__(o)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[int]:
        return self._range.__iter__()

    def __getitem__(self, key: Union[SupportsIndex, slice]) -> int:
        return self._range.__getitem__(key)

    def __reversed__(self) -> Iterator[int]:
        return self._range.__reversed__()

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self._range.__repr__()


class RandomTableEvent(BaseModel):
    name: str
    range: Range


event = RandomTableEvent(name="foo", range="11-34")

print("event:", event)
print("event.range:", event.range)
print("schema:", event.schema_json(indent=2))
print("is instance of range:", isinstance(event.range, range))
print("event.range.start:", event.range.start)
print("event.range.stop:", event.range.stop)
print("event.range[0:5]", event.range[0:5])
print("last 3 elements:", list(event.range[-3:]))
```

Output:

```
event: name='foo' range=range(11, 35)
event.range: range(11, 35)
schema: {
  "title": "RandomTableEvent",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "title": "Name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "range": {
      "title": "Range",
      "pattern": "^(?P<first>[1-6]+)(-(?P<last>[1-6]+))?$",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "range"
  ]
}
is instance of range: False
event.range.start: 11
event.range.stop: 35
event.range[0:5] range(11, 16)
last 3 elements: [32, 33, 34]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that in-depth solution. Wrapping range with a proprietary class seems like a bit off, but I see it solves the problem very elegantly.

Comment: So, the `pattern` in the `__modify_schema__` is used solely for the [json] schema *representation*?  Seems like it -- because it does not seem to be enforced, unless you explicitly check the pattern in the validate method, as you are here. This was unclear to me in the docs.  Thank you for the example.

Comment: @Owen, as far as I understand, you are right: the schema produced by `__modify_schema__` is only informative and does not have any effect on the validations of the model.